# Prove that the open unit ball $ B(0,1) $ is homeomorphic to the open ball $ B(0,r), r > 0 $

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that the open unit ball $ B(0,1) $ considered as a subspace of $ R^{n} $, is homeomorphic to the open ball $ B(0,r), r > 0 $.

Open unit ball $ B(0,1) $ is homeomorphic to $ R^{n} $ and the open ball $ B(0,r), r > 0 $ also is homeomorphic to $ R^{n} $. By transitivity, the open unit ball $ B(0,1) $ is homeomorphic to the open ball $ B(0,r), r > 0 $.

I have proved that $ B(0,1) $ is homeomorphic to $ R^{n} $, how can I prove that  $ B(0,r) $ is homeomorphic to $ R^{n} $?

How can I directly prove that $ B(0,1) $ and $ B(0,r) $ are homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x\rightarrow x/r$ is bicontinuous and bijective.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the map $x \mapsto rx$. This is clearly a continuous bijection with continuous inverse $ x \mapsto \frac{1}{r} x$.

Answer (score 1):

Especially in $\mathbb{R^n}$ you can picture homeomorphisms, which are a smooth deformation of a sort.

How to get from one ball with radius $r$ to another with radius $s$? Simply shrink or expand the balls by some proper constant..